# Is it possible to simulate key presses without a module in python?

Tags: python, module

I know I could use Pynput, and from what I understand modules alter interpreters(like Python) and compilers, using more basic code. So my question is, can I simulate key presses without a module(like Pynput) in python?(also I use the most resent version of Python.v.3, I'm also using windows{I think, I have a hp laptop}.)

Comment: Depends on the platform, but for Windows you could use the built-in ctypes module and access some library functions. At some point you have to interact with the OS, so it's OS-specific, and definitely couldn't be done with just pure Python code that doesn't involve importing any modules at all, including built-in ones.

Comment: @Random Davis Thanks, I honestly didn't expect an answer so fast, again thanks, it helps.

Comment: I wouldn't really consider my comment a full answer, I recommend putting the relevant platform information in your question so that a full answer can be given. For instance, if it's Windows, then an answer could include the relevant library functions to invoke via ctypes.